# Missing libraries for using oAuth2 with google drive on .Net

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the example code working in VB .Net I imported the example Oauth.

The example on the google Drive website is here from where I imported the sample code into VB.Net https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

It has these two references

```
 Imports Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2
 Imports Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Data
```

I cannot find the libraries in the downloads for the libraries above and I getting errors here in the code:

```
    Dim credentials As IAuthorizationState = ExchangeCode(authorizationCode)
    Dim userInfo As Userinfo = GetUserInfo(credentials)
Dim userId As [String] = userInfo.Id
emailAddress = userInfo.Email
```

As userInfo is not defined anywhere. Is it in the missing .dll files?

And

```
    Dim userInfoService As New Oauth2Service(GetAuthenticatorFromState(credentials))
    Dim userInfo As Userinfo = Nothing
```

Oauth2Service cannot be found?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The library you are looking for has a DLL reference, but you have to extract it twice.

Once you extract the initial download (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Google_OAuth2_API), there should be a few zip files in that folder, along with "Lib" and "dependencies" one of them should be:

google-oauth2-v2-rev38-csharp-1.3.0-beta-src.zip or google-oauth2-v2-rev38-csharp-1.3.0-beta-bin.zip
[image]

Extract the zip file that has the binary, and the Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2 dll should be there for you to import into the project.

This should fix the error. It's not obvious, it took me a bit to figure out the situation. This is basically how all the APIs that you download for the .Net library are structured.

I hope this helps.

Comment: added a screen shot as well to the above post.

Comment: thanks! I did figure that out. it works well. Wished that it wasn't zipped up like that, or at least did unzip automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Oauth2 is a standalone service and has additional binaries, download them from http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Google_OAuth2_API

Comment: I did add all the libs that I could find, including the OAuth2. It still cannot find OAuth2Service and Userinfo. Any thoughts? 
   Imports Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2
   Imports Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Data